# How to separate list items in liquid markup?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

In my Jekyll layout template I am creating a meta tag for keywords from the list of tags supplied in a post as follows:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="{{page.tags}}"/>
```

The post has the following YAML front matter:

```
---
layout: post
tags: [personal, blog]
---
```

The generated `meta` tag is as follows:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="personalblog"/>
```

What filter must I use so that the `content` attribute reflects `personal, blog` instead of `personalblog`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer. There's a filter called `join` (similar to the `join` method on JavaScript arrays) which allows you to join the elements of a list into a string.

Thus all I needed to do was:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="{{page.tags | join: ', '}}"/>
```